# sudo can't write to temp file

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm trying to understand why sudo doesn't have permission here

```
touch fred.txt
/tmp$ ls -la fred.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 0 Dec 12 15:40 fred.txt
/tmp$ sudo -i
~# cd /tmp
/tmp# echo hi >> fred.txt
-bash: fred.txt: Permission denied
/tmp# chmod 666 fred.txt
/tmp# ls -la fred.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 me me 0 Dec 12 15:40 fred.txt
/tmp# echo hi >> fred.txt
-bash: fred.txt: Permission denied
id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

As I understand it the permission 666 should give owner, group and other permission to r/w to the file.
Surly sudo which is acting as root as evidenced by the id command has access to the file under the 'other' permission.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has something to do with [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5) in the Linux kernel. Often `/tmp` is "world-writable" ("world" here means "others") and is "sticky":

```
$ stat /tmp/
...
Access: (1777/drwxrwxrwt)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
...
```

`chmod(2)`:

```
...
S_ISVTX  (01000)  sticky bit (restricted deletion flag, as described in unlink(2))
...
S_IWOTH  (00002)  write by others
...
```

As mentioned in the commit message, it doesn't exactly prevent you from writing to an affected file, but from opening such a file with `O_CREAT`, which is a flag for [`open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) that is typically set to trigger file creation if the target does not exist yet. Therefore, you can still write to an affected file with the flag unset (which can be done with `dd`):

```
# ls -l /tmp/meh 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom 0 Dec 12 17:33 /tmp/meh
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
# echo test | dd of=/tmp/meh oflag=append conv=notrunc
dd: failed to open '/tmp/meh': Permission denied
# echo test | dd of=/tmp/meh oflag=append conv=notrunc,nocreat
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
5 bytes copied, 9.4981e-05 s, 52.6 kB/s
#
```

Note that it's purely about whether the flag is set, but not whether a file needs to be created, since in the case of concern, the file always exists.

Also note that, as mentioned in the commit message, the file could not be opened with `O_CREAT` not *just* because it was not owned by user that attempted to open it (`root`), but also because its owner (`tom`) is different from the owner (`root`) of the directory (`/tmp`). If `/tmp/` were owned by `tom` as `/tmp/meh` was, `root` would have been *able* to open it with `O_CREAT`.

Also see [this commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/2732587540035227fe59e4b64b60127352611b35) in systemd which enables the "protection" on distros that adopted it:

```
# sysctl fs.protected_regular
fs.protected_regular = 1
```

Note that the related sysctls [can also be set `2` (or `0`)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5#n225).

Comment: I don't believe a tmpfs is mounted. This is my personal PC.

Comment: You don't need to believe, but only need to check (with e.g. `findmnt /tmp`), and I didn't intend to imply that the behavior is tmpfs-specific anyway. Regardless, I've updated the my answer. Now it should show you the full picture.

Comment: findmnt /tmp returns nothing. If I run findmnt --all I can see the likes of snap uses tmpfs but there is no evidence that /tmp does. I also ran the stat command and it looks like the sticky bit is set. Is there reason for this behaviour? I though root could write to anything?